# SQLCacheDependency with 100000 Records

Tags: asp.net, sql

We are using SQLCache Dependency in our asp.net application. We are storing like 100000 records in the cache is that good practice or we need to find alternate solution because sometimes our server CPU banging 100% due to it and we have to reset application pools.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: sounds like you have answered your own question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you have implemented it; but it sounds like a bad idea. You don't give a lot of details.

If you are storing 100000 records in the same cache bucket, and it gets invalidated; then the next request must retrieve all 100000 records, before it can proceed - even if it only needs  a few of them. If multiple users request the resource at the same time, then they will be placed on queue until the first request finishes retrieving records. It sounds like that could be your problem.

It might be better to store the records in individual cache buckets, or in small batches depending on how much you know about the data and when it will be needed. Then a single request will only need to fetch what it actually needs, before it can proceed.

I don't know how much this answer helps you, but you are not giving very much detail in the question. Feel free to update your question, and you might get better answers.

Comment: What do you mean with "cache bucket"? Is this the key under which an object is stored in the cache, e.g. Cache["_bucket_"] = value;

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into using a cache server like [memcached](https://memcached.org/) or "[Code Name Velocity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/dd187409%28v=sql.100%29)" from Microsoft which is in [CTP3](https://web.archive.org/web/20060719041159/http://www.microsoft.com:80/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en). There is also a [blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/velocity/) for Velocity, and a sample for sql dependency [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20100125130652/http://blogs.microsoft.co.il:80/blogs/hagayalbo/archive/2009/04/20/sql-dependency-with-velocity-ctp3.aspx).

These are both distributed cache servers and should work better for your scenario, and they will scale much better.

Comment: True, but if it is only 100000 records, the built in ASP .NET cache should be able to handle it very well. If he in fact needs to scale up, then this is a good answer.

Comment: I agree 100.000 is small. Even an internal dictionary could handle it. Depending on how the dependency triggers work in his code, maybe Velocity would perform better. Also we don't know the size or structure of the cached data.

Comment: Event simpler I have tried with AppFaric but now CPU is not going 100% but the speed of the size is incredibly slow.